# Expected value of the number of white balls in a box

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value

In a box there are $k$ white and $l$ black balls, and next to the box there are $m$ white and $m$ black balls. Out of the box one ball is randomly taken out and then returned to the box also with $m$ more balls of the same color.

a) Find expected value of the number of white balls that are now in the box

b) If now we are picking a ball out of the box, what is the probability that it will be white?

b) Hypotheses:

$H_{1}:$ I have taken a white ball out of the box

$H_{2}:$ I have taken a black ball out of the box

Let A be the probability we are looking for:

$P(A)=P(A\setminus H_{1})P(H_{1})+P(A\setminus H_{2})P(H_{2})=\frac{k+m}{k+m+l}\frac{k}{k+l}+\frac{k}{k+m+l}\frac{l}{k+l}$

a) I am not really sure how to solve this, I was thinking of a random variable $X$ that will represent number of white balls in a box, and it can only take values $k$ or $k+m$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track and can apply:

$$\mathbb EX=\mathbb E[X\mid H_1]P(H_1)+\mathbb E[X\mid H_2]P(H_2)$$

Just as you did with finding $P(A)$.

Comment: I just haven't seen that formula anywhere in my textbook, so I got a bit confused. $X\setminus H_{1}$ - it's distribution will be: value  $k+m$ with probability $\frac{k}{k+l}$, it will have that many white balls only if I take out one white ball, so that is why I put that probability. And random variable $X\setminus H_{2}$ will have value $k$ with probability $\frac{l}{k+l}$. Finally I get $E(X)=\frac{(k+m)k}{k+l}P(H_{1})+\frac{kl}{k+l}P(H_{2})$, If I understood correctly..

Comment: $\mathbb E[X|H_1]=k+m$ and $\mathbb E[X|H_2]=k$. These values must be substituted in the expression in my answer.

Comment: @untitled why do you have $P(H_1)$ and $P(H_2)$ in the final value of $E(X)$? You already multiplied by $P(H_1)$ and $P(H_2)$. So if you remove them, that is your answer. By the way, the interesting part is that in the absence of us knowing the color of the first ball, the probability of the 2nd ball being white is independent of m = $\frac{k}{k+l}$. Pls check.

Comment: Thank you, understood it